# What is `rubygems-update`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What does the gem [`rubygems-update`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update) do? The manual says it is an update to the gem, but it is not clear what that means. I already had gem (version 1.8.25) installed on my computer, but I was able to install `rubygems-update` version 1.8.25 (the same version number as `gem`) on top of that, resulting in gem version 1.8.25. What does that mean? What is the difference between doing:

```
gem update --system
```

and

```
update_rubygems
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What does the gem rubygems-update do?

   `rubygems-update` is the gem containing the `gem` command, which it installs to your ruby bin directory, so you can use commands like `gem install` and so on.
2. What does it mean that you can install the gem `rubygems-update` with the same version number as the version number appearing when you call `gem --version`?

   The version number of rubygems-update *is* the version number the `gem` command puts out when asked to. If you cd to the contents of `rubygems-update`, and go to the file `command_manager.rb`, you will find the following on line 138:

   ```
   when '-v', '--version'
   say Gem::VERSION
   terminate_interaction(0)
   ```

   So, your ability to install `rubygems-update`, what does it mean? Which leads to the third question:
3. What is the difference between `gem update --system` and `update_rubygems`?

   There is little. Actually, `gem update --system [VERSION]` is just a wrapper for the two following commands:

   ```
   gem install rubygems-update -v [VERSION]
   update_rubygems
   ```

   To see the actual code executing `gem update --system`, cd to the contents of `rubygems-update`, and look at the file `update_command.rb`. You can do `gem update --system -v` to get a verbose output of what it is doing.

Comment: I don't think your 3. is correct. I have done `gem update --system` many times, but I was still able to install `rubygems-update` by doing `gem instlal rubygems-update`, which means that `gem update --system` had not installed `rubygems-update`.

Comment: @sawa The `gem install` command always installs the gem afaik, it just does not fetch from remote if it has the source available. If you do `gem uninstall rubygems-update`, remove all versions of it, and then do `gem install rubygems-update -v 1.8.20` (as an example, you can upgrade again later) and then `gem update --system 1.8.20`, you will see that the gem is not fetched from remote (because the source is already there), which will happen if you use `gem update --system 1.8.20` directly. Also the output of `gem update --system` shows it is indeed installing the gem.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to have been my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

As you know RubyGems is a package management framework for Ruby and gems is an update for the same.

```
gem update --system
```

It is the normal upgrade policy. 
For an older version of RubyGems installed, it is done in the two steps as follows in two steps:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Comment: While what you wrote is probably correct, it does not answer my question.

Comment: @sawa please elaborate what you want to know.

Comment: I gave three clearly interrogative question sentences. You answered none of them. I will not elaborate it any further.